# Can't load the XML file?

Tags: php, xml, file-get-contents

http://westwood-backup.com/podcast?categoryID2=403

This is the XML file that i want to load and echo via PHP. I tried file_get_contents and load. Both of are return empty string. If i change the URL as another XML file, functions works great. What can be special about the URL?

```
<?php 
$content = file_get_contents("http://westwood-backup.com/podcast?categoryID2=403");
echo $content;
?>
```

Another try with load, same empty result.

```
<?php 
$feed = new DOMDocument();
if (@$feed->load("http://westwood-backup.com/podcast?categoryID2=403")) { 
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($feed);
    $linkPath = $xpath->query("/rss/channel/link");
    echo $linkPath
}
?>
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting and display errors on screen.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`   You'll see the request fail.  Possibly they are blocking requests from certain http user agents.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Right. Catch the error "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!" How can i surpass this limitation?

Comment: Interestingly, it fails immediately for me using `file_get_contents()` using the http stream wrapper. Using `curl_exec()` in PHP, it hangs and never returns a response. If I use `curl` from the command line, it returns the correct response immediately.

Comment: it works if you did it in curl and set a timeout + user agent. see answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CURL and you can do it like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://westwood-backup.com/podcast?categoryID2=403');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, ' Mozilla/1.22 (compatible; MSIE 2.0d; Windows NT)');
$xml = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($xml);
echo "</pre>";
```

Outputs:

[image]

---

I think the server implements a "User-Agent" check to make sure the XML data is only loaded within a browser (not via bots/file_get_contents etc...)

so, by using CURL and setting a dummy user-agent, you can get around the check and load the data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a useragent header that the server is happy with. No need for cUrl if you dont want to use it, you can use `stream_context_create` with `file_get_contents`:

```
$options = array(
        'http'=>array(
            'method'=>"GET",
            'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
                "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.102011-10-16 20:23:10\r\n" // i.e. An iPad
        )
    );

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$content = file_get_contents("http://westwood-backup.com/podcast?categoryID2=403", false, $context);
echo $content;
```